# links not working in ipad /iphone

Tags: jquery-mobile

We're trying to put a fixed navigation to scroll the different sections of a page.
i have 3 links to link to different sections of the same page. and the position of the div containing this links are fixed.i am caling a function when that link clicked.

We're using jquery scrollTo().to scroll.it is wrking fine on desktop applications.

Only on ipad, the first click pass without problem, but after this one, the on the navigation seems to be disabled. If we scroll, even a little bit, with the hand, then the link's work again.

I used:

```
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);    
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 1);
```

ofter scrollto but no luck....

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile anchor linking will prevent you from doing that. you might have to write a custom js to do the scroll.
More here - 
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-anchor-linking